# How many total order relations on a set $A$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, notation, cardinals, relations

Let's define a set $T_A$ which is the set of all total order relations on $A$.

This set is a subset of the set of all $2$-adic relations on $A$: $$T_A \subset \mathcal P(A^2) $$

1-Which is the cardinality of $T_A$?

2-Which is the standard notation for the set $T_A$?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard notation for this one.

Comment: [Related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/165010/28900)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note if $<$ is a total order on $A$ then for every permutation of $A$, $\pi$, the relation $\{\langle \pi a,\pi b\rangle\mid a<b\}$ is a total order on $A$ as well. In fact it is isomorphic to $<$.

**Additional Hint:** If $A$ is finite, then there is only one linear order of $A$ (up to isomorphism); if $A$ is infinite then there cannot be more orders than $2^A$, and there are $2^A$ permutations.

Comment: Mmh. I can understand from  $T_A \subset \mathcal P(A^2)$  that   $|T_A|<2^{|A|^2}$  but can you explain why  $|T_A|<2^{|A|}$? And do you mean not all total orders on a infinite set all isomorphic?Sorry for that but I am a newwbye in set theory and combinatorics.

Comment: @MphLee: Assuming the axiom of choice, $A\times A$ is equipotent with $A$, for every infinite $A$. Therefore $2^{A^2}=2^A$. And yes, if $A$ is infinite then it has many non-isomorphic linear orders. For example, the natural numbers have a linear order of the order type of the integers, and another of the order type of the rationals. These cannot be isomorphic at all.

Comment: But then... if $A$ is infinite than $|T_A|$ is infinite (right?) and not bigger than $2^{|A|}$ but what is the real value of $|T_A|$? Example: a set of cardinality $\aleph_0$ will have less (or same because a infinite set can have subset with same cardinality) total orders than  $2^{\aleph_0}$ but not a finite cardinality. so $\aleph_0 \le|T_A|\le2^{\aleph_0}$...$|T_A|$ Is or is not it countable? And how works for bigger cardinality?

Comment: @MphLee: One you prove that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ permutations of $\Bbb N$ it follows immediately that there are *at least* $2^{\aleph_0}$ linear orders of $\Bbb N$. But much more is true in this case. There are in fact $2^{\aleph_0}$ **non-isomorphic** linear orders for $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this question yourself. There has to be a unique minimum in the order, then a unique element above that, and so on. So you get a bijection, form a standard chain $I_n$ on $n=\#A$ elements to $A$, which preserves order (you can take $I_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for instance, then $i$ maps to the $i$-th smallest element). Moreover every bijection $f:I_n\to A$ defines a unique total ordering $\leq_f$ on $A$, by the rule $f(x)\leq_f f(y)$ whenever $x\leq y$ in $I_n$.

How many bijections $f:I_n\to A$ are there?

Comment: Mmmh.. thanks for your hint, but i think i don't understand things like "standard chains" and what $\#A$ is yet. Can you give me some links and references so i'll try to find the solution?

Comment: A standard chain is any one fixed totally ordered set of a given size, and $\#A$ is the size of $A$. So if $\#A=n$ you could take $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with '$<$' to be the standard chain. But it really doesn't matter which totally ordered set you use; personally I prefer $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. I just didn't want to impose that choice on anybody.

Comment: $\#A$ is the cardinality? Sorry i was confused because i always used $|A|$ or $card(A)$.

Comment: Sorry about that, just too many notations floating around. One may pronounce # as "number", which makes it a reasonable symbol to use here.

Comment: mmh but. the $I_n$ standard chain of size $n$ is the ordinal $n$ right?

Comment: Yes, if you like. And then $I_n=n=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ would explain my preference. But talking about a bijection $n\to A$ would probably be a bit confusing.

Comment: In other words (if i have understood)  $|T_A|=|Bij(|A|,A)|$  where   $Bij(|A|,A)$  is the sets of all the  $2$-adic relations that are bijections from  $|A|=n$ and $A$. But is a loop for me, because I don't know how to calculate the bijections betwen two sets... I'm a bit confused xd, maybe I'm making this more complicated than it is.

Comment: To count bijections between to finite sets of size $n$, count the number of possibilities for the image of the first element, multiply by the number of (remaining) possibilities for the next element, and so forth until all elements have been mapped.

Comment: so ..$n\times(n-1)\times...\times1=n!$ owh! thanks