# Cardinal of all well-orders of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: cardinals, well-orders

Lets consider the set 
$$
A = \{R\subset\mathbb{N}^2:R \text{ is a well-order of } \mathbb{N}\}
$$
Now, it's clear that $\aleph_1\leq|A|\leq2^{\aleph_0}$(Since all the well-orders of $\mathbb{N}$ are isomorphic to some $\alpha<\aleph_1$ which gives $\aleph_1\leq|A|$ and every well-order of  $\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$, of which there are $2^{\aleph_0}$, giving $|A|\leq2^{\aleph_0}$)

If we were to assume the [Continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) then it clearly follows $|A|=\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}$(By Cantor-Berstein theorem)

However in ZFC, I'm not sure how to procced, I think that $|A|=2^{\aleph_0}$, but I do not know how to prove this or if this is right. Any idea on what to do?

Comment: Btw, I just realised it's been answered before: <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165010/number-of-well-ordering-relations-on-a-well-orderable-infinite-set-a>.  and here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112651/how-many-well-orderings-of-aleph-0-are-there?newreg=ccb0d188f8c54a18949d8b131dfc30fd Please tell me if you want me to delete this post

Comment: No,  don't delete it. We don't delete duplicate questions, we close them as duplicates, with a pointer to the previously answered question. In fact you can close it yourself with the "close" button at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix some well-order on $\Bbb N^2$.

Take a countably infinite sequence of natural numbers $a = (a_1, a_2, \ldots)$, and define a well-order on $\Bbb N^2$ as follows:

- $(i,a_i)$ comes before $(j, a_j)$ iff $i$ is less than $j$ (under the standard ordering on $\Bbb N$)
- Any point of the form $(i, a_i)$ is before any point not of that form
- For any two points not on the form $(i, a_i)$, compare using the fixed well-order

(don't forget to prove that this is actually a well-order). This gives an injection (show this too, of course) from the set of infinite sequences of natural numbers (which has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$) to the set of well-orderings of $\Bbb N^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try that!

Comment: OK, but why not just show that $\mathbb N$ admits $2^{\aleph_0}$ orderings which are isomorphic to the standard ordering, i.e., orderings of type $\omega$? There is one of those for each bijection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.

Comment: @bof I could've done that. Ordering each copy of $\{n\}\times \Bbb N$ according to some $\omega$-type ordering. But I don't see that as much easier, really.

Comment: Who said anything about ordering copies og $\{n\}\times\mathbb N$? I mean, for each bijection $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, define an ordering $\lt_f$ of $\mathbb N$ by $$m\lt_f n\iff f(m)\lt f(n).$$ Zap, $2^{\aleph_0}$ well-orderings of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @bof I realize I completely misread the question as being primarily about well-orders of $\Bbb N^2$. Well dang. Why not post your suggestion as an actual answer to the question?