# Non-isomorphic well-orderings on a set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let $X$ be a non-empty arbitrary (even infinite) set. It is well known that there exists at least a well-ordering on $X$. Actually, there are different well-orderings on $X$. Many of them turn out to be isomorphic. So my question is: how many non-isomorphic well-orderings is it possible to construct on an arbitrary non-empty ground set $X$? Something is said here:

[Number of well-ordering relations on a well-orderable infinite set $A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165010/number-of-well-ordering-relations-on-a-well-orderable-infinite-set-a)

but it would be interesting for me to have a complete answer to my question, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We work in ZFC, so every set can be well-ordered.

If $A$ is finite, there is only one well-order of it. This is not hard to see.

If $A$ is infinite and of size $\kappa$, then each non-isomorphic well-ordering corresponds to a unique ordinal of size $\kappa$. There are exactly $\kappa^+$ ordinals of size $\kappa$, and so there are $\kappa^+$ non-isomorphic well-orderings of $A$. As Sassatelli points out, this is what Hartogs' Lemma says.

Comment: 1) The discussion is ZF isn't really different: if $A$ is well-orderable, then it's in bijection with an initial ordinal and the same conclusions apply; if it isn't, then there are $0$ well-orderings on it. 2) The person was Hartogs, not Hartog. 3) I do believe that the idea is in Hartogs' lemma, but there are still some details to fill, as mundane as they may be: namely, dealing effectively with the fact that $\kappa^+$ is the set of ordinals of cardinality $\le\kappa$, not of cardinality $\kappa$.

Comment: Correct. The typo has been fixed.